# How to calculate distance between five markers?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, haversine

How do you calculate the distance between five markers in Google maps V3? I know I have to use Haversine formula which I researched and even found a post in here teaching on calculating the distance between two markers. What if I want to calculate it between five markers ? Been trying for a few hours but the km calculated is so wrong. Thanks

Following codes are below:

```
// compute distance between the two points
    var R = 6371; // KM
    var dLat = toRad(location5.lat()-location4.lat()-location3.lat()-location2.lat()-location1.lat());
    var dLon = toRad(location5.lng()-location4.lng()-location3.lng()-location2.lng()-location1.lng()); 

    var dLat1 = toRad(location1.lat());
    var dLat2 = toRad(location2.lat());
    var dLat3 = toRad(location3.lat());
    var dLat4 = toRad(location4.lat());
    var dLat5 = toRad(location5.lat());

    var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
            Math.cos(dLat1) * Math.cos(dLat1) * 
            Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2); 
    var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
    var d = R * c;

    document.getElementById("distance_direct").innerHTML = "<br/><br/><br/>The distance between the five points (in a straight line) is: "+d +" Km.";
}

function toRad(deg) 
{
    return deg * Math.PI/180;
}
```

I guess my wrong part is with the line starting with var a formula. Please indicate my error if im wrong and maybe a solution to help?

Comment: What does 'the distance between five markers' mean?

Comment: Isn't this just additive (Distance between Marker A & B + Distance between B & C + etc., etc.)?

Comment: @AakashM It means the distance between the five coordinates point join by a line in google map.

Comment: @KevinDTimm I did try what you said a few hours ago but I just couldn't get it to work correctly. Is it possible for you to edit mine or post up a solution please ?

Comment: Surely then you just add the distances A-B, B-C etc, since you say you know how to calculate the distance between two points?

Comment: @AakashM I understand that I just have to add the distance up and I've tried copjon method but it somehow isn't working for me. Still trying though.. Honestly, I'm not really good at coding so if you could enlighten me by editing my codes or post a solution, I would thank you from the bottom of my heart.

Answer (score 2):

The computeLength() function in google maps V3 should give you what you need, see http://code.google.com/intl/el/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry.html#Distance

Answer (score 0):

The function you are using is for the distance between two coordinates. You need to calculate the distance from A->B then B->C and then add those distances up at the end.

```
var distAB = calcDist(location1,location2);
var distBC = calcDist(location2,location3);
var distCD = calcDist(location3,location4);
var distDE = calcDist(location4,location5);

var distTotal = distAB + distBC + distCD + distDE;

function calcDist(locationA,locationB)
{
    var R = 6371; // KM
    var dLat = toRad(locationB.lat()) - toRad(locationA.lat());
    var dLng = toRad(locationB.lng()) - toRad(locationA.lng());
    var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
        Math.cos(dLat1) * Math.cos(dLat1) * 
        Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2); 
    var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
    return R * c;
}

function toRad(deg) 
{
    return deg * Math.PI/180;
}
```

Comment: The Javascript is probably wrong where I'm passing those location objects (I don't work with JS a whole lot). But if you want to do the calculation, that is how to do it.